# How to use binary data in Rails fixtures?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, binary, fixtures

Assume you want to test your brand new `Picture` model. Probably you want to test whether or not your automatic conversions are working. How do you feed the test data into your fixtures?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To achieve this create a file `file_fixtures_extension.rb` in your app's folder under `config/initializers` containing the following code:

```
require 'active_record/fixtures'

module FileFixtureExtension
  def file(file_name)
    File::open(Rails.root.join('test/fixtures/', file_name), 'rb') do |f|
      "!!binary \"#{Base64.strict_encode64(f.read)}\""
    end
  end
end

Fixture.extend FileFixtureExtension
```

Now, you can include binary data from the file `test/fixtures/pictures/my-birthday.jpg` in your fixtures like this:

```
first_picture:
  name: My Birthday
  filename: my-birthday.jpg
  content_type: image/jpeg
  file: <%=Fixture::file 'pictures/my-birthday.jpg' %>
```

For further reading on binary data in YAML take a look at the [YAML documentation](http://yaml.org/type/binary.html).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Rails 6 `NameError: uninitialized constant Fixture`.